# Cut array by sub array key value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I got this array

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1411667077)
    ["nachricht"]=>
    string(13) "iiiiiiiiiiiii"
    ["user"]=>
    string(15) "334607943355808"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(16) "25.09.2014 19:44"
    ["deleted"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1411701734)
    ["nachricht"]=>
    string(2) "dd"
    ["user"]=>
    string(15) "334607943355808"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(16) "26.09.2014 05:22"
    ["deleted"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1411701737)
    ["nachricht"]=>
    string(6) "swfsfs"
    ["user"]=>
    string(15) "334607943355808"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(16) "26.09.2014 05:22"
    ["deleted"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1411701739)
    ["nachricht"]=>
    string(7) "egwegeg"
    ["user"]=>
    string(15) "334607943355808"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(16) "26.09.2014 05:22"
    ["deleted"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1411742201)
    ["nachricht"]=>
    string(3) "sss"
    ["user"]=>
    string(15) "334607943355808"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(16) "26.09.2014 16:36"
    ["deleted"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

I want to cut the where the `id` is `1411701737` so I tryed:

```
foreach($array as $arr => $sub_arr)
{
    if $sub_arr['id'] == 1411701737
    {
         break;
    }
 }
```

I know I need to create a whole new array in the foreach, but isn't there maybe a build in function?

Comment: define "cut" a little better for us, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr_new = array(); //Define a new array
foreach($arr_old as $a) { //Loop through the old one
   if($a['id'] === 1411701737) break; //If the value of id matches, leave the foreach loop
   $arr_new[] = $a; //Else, copy this array to the new array
}
print_r($arr_new); //Print the new array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new = array();
foreach($array as $k) {

   if($k['id'] == 1411701737) break;
   array_push($new, $k);

}

var_dump($new);
```

The answer by Mooseman is likely a faster way to do this since it does not rely on a PHP function call to place the array into the new array. However unless you are doing this on a set of arrays that is in the 100k+ it really won't matter.

Comment: I get array(24) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(2) and so on with it :/

Comment: I changed my code once are you using the newest one? I tested this with the array that you have provided and it worked.

Comment: Oh now I tryed and it also works, thank you too. The performance is also very importment because it will be a chat